# Crear una clase que genere un frame y subclases para crear widgets dento del frame #Pyhton

Tags: python, poo, tkinter

estoy aprendeindo Python, he realizado una clase que genera un frame pero no puedo lograra una sub clase que gener un label o Entry o List que lo genere dento de la clase principal Frame.
Les dejo el codigo

```
from tkinter import Tk,Label,Button,Entry, Frame

class FrSuma(Frame):

 def __init__(self, master=None): 
    super().__init__(master, width=300, height=300, bg="blue")
    self.master=master
    self.place(x=10,y=10)
    self.name=""

def ubi(self, px,py,an,al,col):
    self.px=px
    self.py=py
    self.an=an
    self.al=al
    self.col=col
    self.place(x=self.px, y=self.py)
    self.config(width=self.an, height=self.al, bg=self.col)

def L(self):

    self=Label(text="ddd",bg='black')
    self.place(x=10, y=20)


root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Suma de numeros")
root.config(width=1000,height=400)

a=FrSuma(root)
a.ubi(50,20,100,100,"green")
b=FrSuma(root)
b.ubi(50,150,100,100,"blue")
x=b.L()

root.mainloop()
```

Lo que se ve en fondo negro es el label pero queda en el root (principal) pero no dentro de los frame (Verde o azul), frmaes generados con las clase FrSuma.No puedo lograr que el Label o Entry o List tomen el master de la clase FrSuma que crea el frame Desde ya Muchas Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El Label se añada dentro del Frame generado por la clase FrSuma, debes especificar la propiedad master en el constructor de Label. En este caso, la propiedad master debe ser el objeto self, que representa el Frame generado por la clase FrSuma. Un ejemplo podría ser

```
class FrSuma(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None): 
        super().__init__(master, width=300, height=300, bg="blue")
        self.master=master
        self.place(x=10,y=10)
        self.name=""

    def ubi(self, px,py,an,al,col):
        self.px=px
        self.py=py
        self.an=an
        self.al=al
        self.col=col
        self.place(x=self.px, y=self.py)
        self.config(width=self.an, height=self.al, bg=self.col)

    def L(self):
        label = Label(self, text="ddd",bg='black')
        label.place(x=10, y=20)
```

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar ; [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido)